# Height 100% for dynamic iframe in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, iframe

Can anyone tell me what are the steps to make a iframe with external src have 100% height without scrolling?

The height is dynamic, changing daily.

I tried several versions, to no avail.

Now I found a plugin that would say something, but fail to implement it.

What I tried:

1. I downloaded the files from "JS" https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer
2. I put them in mytheme / lib / js
3. I created in function.php

   ```
   function resize() {
   wp_register_script( 'resize1', get_template_directory_uri().'/lib/js/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js', array( 'jquery' ));
   wp_register_script( 'resize2', get_template_directory_uri().'/lib/js/iframeResizer.min.js', array( 'jquery' ));
   wp_enqueue_script( 'resize1' );
   wp_enqueue_script( 'resize2' );
   }
   ```

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'resize');

4. And i use iframe but not work.

< iframe src="site_link" frameborder="0" scroll="no">

I done wrong? I can do something about iframe?

Comment: is iframe on same domain as page?

Comment: No, different domain.

Comment: unless you control other domain you can't access inside iframe due to `same origin policy`